# LINQ distinct on groups of information

Tags: c#, linq

I have multiple items (List)

I need to get distinct features for the items but the issue is that each item has two features. So both features need to match on GroupTypeId and GroupId to become a distinct group.

I need to group items that have the same features (per above distinct groups found). I don't need features here again at the item level since I will have these per above in a separate object.

I need to keep items order intact, the first item will go in group 1, then second might go in group 1 or group 2 and so on.

Also, each item in group, item number needs to be overwritten per the new sequence in that group.

Can i do above tasks purely with LINQ rather than using nested loops?

In the below sample for items

- i have 3 distinct feature groups
- and 3 item groups. Item 2 and 4 needs to be grouped together and the line no needs to change to 1 and 2. For item 1 and 3, line number should become as 1.

Need to add to List whose count will be 3

- Index[0] will have 2 features and 1 item
- Index[1] will have 2 features and 2 items
- Index[2] will have 2 features and 1 item

```
public class ItemPicked
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public List<ItemFeature> Features { get; set; }
}
public class ItemFeature
{
    public string OriginalReceived { get; set; }
    public Group Feature { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string GroupTypeId { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public int SequenceNo { get; set; }
}

public class PickedGrouping
{
    public List<ItemFeature> Features { get; set; }
    public List<ItemPicked> Items { get; set; }
}


var SampleFeatures1 = new List<ItemFeature>() {
    new ItemFeature {
        OriginalReceived = "SomeThing",
        Feature = new Group() {
            Id = 1, SequenceNo = 1, GroupTypeId = "A", GroupId = "B"
        }
    },
    new ItemFeature {
        OriginalReceived = "SomeThing2",
        Feature = new Group() {
            Id = 2, SequenceNo = 2, GroupTypeId = "Y", GroupId = "Z"
        }
    }
};

var SampleFeatures2 = new List<ItemFeature>() {
    new ItemFeature {
        OriginalReceived = "SomeThing3",
        Feature = new Group() {
            Id = 3, SequenceNo = 3, GroupTypeId = "C", GroupId = "D"
        }
    },
    new ItemFeature {
        OriginalReceived = "SomeThing4",
        Feature = new Group() {
            Id = 4, SequenceNo = 4, GroupTypeId = "X", GroupId = "Y"
        }
    }
};

var SampleFeatures3 = new List<ItemFeature>() {
    new ItemFeature {
        OriginalReceived = "SomeThing5",
        Feature = new Group() {
            Id = 3, SequenceNo = 3, GroupTypeId = "C", GroupId = "D"
        }
    },
    new ItemFeature {
        OriginalReceived = "SomeThing5",
        Feature = new Group() {
            Id = 2, SequenceNo = 2, GroupTypeId = "M", GroupId = "K"
        }
    }
};

var items = new List<ItemPicked>(){
    new ItemPicked{
        Id = 1, Description = "Item 1", LineNumber = 1, Features = SampleFeatures1
    },
    new ItemPicked{
        Id = 2, Description = "Item 2", LineNumber = 2, Features = SampleFeatures2
    },
    new ItemPicked{
        Id = 3, Description = "Item 3", LineNumber = 3, Features = SampleFeatures3
    },
    new ItemPicked{
        Id = 4, Description = "Item 4", LineNumber = 4, Features = SampleFeatures2
    }
};


var pickedGroupings = new List<PickedGrouping>();
PickedGrouping selectedGroup = null;

foreach (var item in items)
{
    var found = 0;
    if(item.Features == null || !item.Features.Any())
    {
        selectedGroup = pickedGroupings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Features == null || !x.Features.Any());
        if (selectedGroup == null) selectedGroup = new PickedGrouping();
        selectedGroup.Features.AddRange(item.Features);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var feature in item.Features)
        {
            foreach (var pg in pickedGroupings)
            {
                if ((item.Features == null || !item.Features.Any()) && (pg.Features == null || !pg.Features.Any())){
                    selectedGroup = pg;
                    found += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var pgf in pg.Features)
                    {
                        if (pgf.Feature == null) continue;
                        if (pgf.Feature.GroupId == feature.Feature.GroupId && pgf.Feature.GroupTypeId == feature.Feature.GroupTypeId)
                        {
                            selectedGroup = pg;
                            found += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (found < 2)
        {
            pickedGroupings.Add(new PickedGrouping() { Features = item.Features });
            selectedGroup = pickedGroupings[pickedGroupings.Count - 1];
        }
    }

    //add item
    if (selectedGroup.Items == null) selectedGroup.Items = new List<ItemPicked>();
    selectedGroup.Items.Add(item);
}

//update line number
foreach(var pg in pickedGroupings)
{
    var lineNum = 1;
    foreach(var item in pg.Items)
    {
        item.LineNumber = lineNum;
        lineNum += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm...can't seem to format the code...

Comment: Indent the code with 4 spaces.

Comment: I am only able to format it by putting the dummy line before and after.

Comment: I've edited it, you can also use three backticks (`) to start and end code zone: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code